# How to check for deeplink in notification content?

Tags: android

How can I check if a particular notification on my android device has deep link information?

I'm using a service which sends me a notification but when I click it, their library isn't responding to the link.

I was curious, I wanted to know if I can check the content of the notification on Android and see if there's some deeplink info there.

I found out about `adb shell dumpsys notification`, and I wanted to know if I can use this to determine if the link has deeplink info or not. But I don't really have an example of how a deeplink would look there.

Or is it actually possible / depends on the implementation?